# How to display mySQL rows even if there are not SUM results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to display a report from mySQL. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT *,
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN alerts_data_status = 'goal' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS goal, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN alerts_data_status = 'delivered' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS delivered, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN alerts_data_status = 'closed' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS closed
FROM   alerts_data 
WHERE  alerts_data.company_id = 1
GROUP  BY alerts_data.alerts_data_id
```

the thing is that if a `alerts_data.id` has 0 goal, 0 delivered, 0 closed, it won't be shown in the results. The query shows only the `alerts_data.id` with at least 1 goal or 1 delivered or 1 closed.

How can I achieve this?

Example output

```
company ---- id --- goal --- delivered --- closed
1 ---- 32 --- 1 ------ 4 ----- 10
1 ---- 11 --- 0 ------ 1 ----- 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Is there a table containing all the `alerts_data_id`s?

Comment: @forpas yes, the "alerts_list" table. In the "alerts_data" table, if an "alerts_data_id" has no goal, no delivered, no closed, then there is no row for the exact "alert_data_id".

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` of `alerts_list` to `alerts_data`:

```
SELECT t.alerts_id,
  SUM(a.alerts_data_status = 'goal') AS goal, 
  SUM(a.alerts_data_status = 'delivered') AS delivered, 
  SUM(a.alerts_data_status = 'closed') AS closed
FROM alerts_list AS t LEFT JOIN alerts_data AS a 
ON a.alerts_data_id = t.alerts_id AND a.company_id = t.company_id 
WHERE t.company_id = 1
GROUP BY t.alerts_data_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but what happens when there is no row for the speicific id in the "alerts_data" table. I mean, the entry for the id at the "alerts_list" is there, but that does not necessarily means that there is an entry for that id in the "alerts_data" as well.

Comment: With the LEFT JOIN you will get 1 row for each id of alerts_list even if it does not exist in alerts_data.

Comment: I understand. The output query now shows those results that do not have any goal, delivered, closed however, it shows not only company_id =1 results. It shows from other companies too, having a NULL at the "select alerts_data.company_id"

Comment: I am trying to make this work: `FROM   alerts_list 
       LEFT JOIN alerts_data
         ON ( alerts_data.alerts_data_id = alerts_list.alerts_id 
              AND alerts_data.company_id = alerts_list.company_id ) 
WHERE  alerts_data.company_id = 1`

Comment: ok, but using the answer above, it shows me all the other t.alerts_id from the other companies as NULL in the "company_id" column

Comment: Now I see that there is a column company_id in alerts_list. Is this correct? If it is then I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue that you are having is that there are *no* rows in the table for the company.  Use an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 1 as company_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'goal'), 0) AS goal, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'delivered'), 0) AS delivered, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'closed'), 0) AS closed
FROM alerts_data ad
WHERE ad.company_id = 1;
```

This no `GROUP BY`, this is guaranteed to return one row -- even if the `WHERE` clause filters out all rows.  A `GROUP BY` returns one row per group, so if all rows are filtered out, then there are no groups and no rows in the result set.

If you wanted to support multiple company ids, you could use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT company_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'goal'), 0) AS goal, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'delivered'), 0) AS delivered, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'closed'), 0) AS closed
FROM (SELECT 1 as company_id UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as company_id
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     alerts_data ad
     USING (company_id)
GROUP BY company_id;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` guarantees that there are rows for each company, so each will be in the result set.

You can also phrase this as:

```
SELECT 1 as company_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'goal'), 0) AS goal, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'delivered'), 0) AS delivered, 
       COALESCE(SUM(alerts_data_status = 'closed'), 0) AS closed
FROM alerts_data ad
WHERE ad.company_id = 1;
```

This no `GROUP BY`, this is guaranteed to return one row -- even if the `WHERE` clause filters out all rows.  A `GROUP BY` returns one row per group, so if all rows are filtered out, then there are no groups and no rows in the result set.

If you wanted to support multiple company ids, you could use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.company_id,
       COALESCE(SUM(ad.alerts_data_status = 'goal'), 0) AS goal, 
       COALESCE(SUM(ad.alerts_data_status = 'delivered'), 0) AS delivered, 
       COALESCE(SUM(ad.alerts_data_status = 'closed'), 0) AS closed
FROM companies c LEFT JOIN
     alerts_data ad
     on c.company_id = ad.company_id
WHERE c.company_id IN (1)   -- or a longer list
GROUP BY c.company_id;
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the answer. Exactly, the thing is that the "alerts_data" has no rows for the exact company and for the exact alert. I have just edited my output in order to make this clearer. I have edited my query following your 1st suggestion without any luck though. I guess my edited output is more on the point now.